# millenial media titanium zero content length returned

Tags: appcelerator, millennial-media

I have [appcelerator](/questions/tagged/appcelerator) and am trying to use [millennial-media](/questions/tagged/millennial-media) to deploy ads.

Currently I am receiving the following error message:

```
Millennial ad return failed. Zero content length returned.
```

Can someone tell me the steps I need to take to resolve this?

My code for the ad is:

```js
return millennialMediaModule.createView({
    apid: "blahblah"
    bottom: 0,
        width: 320,
height: 50,
    adType: millennialMediaModule.TYPE_BANNER
});
```

Comment: downvoter! was something wrong?

Comment: Unsure who downvoted, but I did remove some extraneous content from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah, i got it wrong.

first you'll need an apid - go to [the developer page](https://tools.mmedia.com/apps/appsDashboard) and then the "aps and sites" to get one), let's say they give you the apid of "1". now you put that into your code:

```
millennialMediaModule.createView({ 
    apid: "1", //this here is it! 
    bottom: 0, 
    width: 320, 
    height: 50, 
    adType: millennialMediaModule.TYPE_BANNER 
});
```

now run this, and nothing will happen. you need to get your device id - run your app once with the millennial module trying to call an ad - and then you'll get told your "device id".

it will be in the logs , under something like

```
[INFO] : MillennialMediaSDK: Diagnostic - ********** Millennial Device Id *****************
```

*then* you need (and this is undocumented everywhere but here!) to to go the millennial developer's page ([the same one you got your apid from](https://tools.mmedia.com/apps/appsDashboard), then "aps and sites" and then "test devices") and enter that id - the device id - there.

for some reason you can give it a name, pick whatever you like (i called mine "name").

NOW you rerun your ap, keep the apid the same as what you originally generated (in this example, "1") and hooray! you have an ad! probably!

the device id, then, doesn't appear in your code, only on their site. the apid appears in both your code, and their site (and should be the same in both!)